# Uncaught ReferenceError: toastr is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, client, toastr

I'm trying to use the toastr library within my .NET Core 3.1 Project.

I've added the client side librarys

[image]

I've also included the references in my head tag in my .cshtml razer file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/lib/toastr.js/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/lib/toastr.js/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The issue I'm facing is when I try to use toastr above I get the error "Uncaught referrence error: toastr is undefined"

```
<script> toastr.success("s");</script>
```

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You appear to be including the `toastr` library 3 times, why is that? Any other errors on your browser console?

Comment: @DavidG no reason just trial and error. I can confirm not getting any other browser errors

Comment: Trial and error.... if you do not remove the duplicates, it may do weird things.

Comment: My only guess is that you call `toastr` before the script is loaded on the page. That is an assumption since we do not know where you have the scripts loaded.

Comment: `toastr` (and any 3rd party jquery plugins) **MUST** come after jquery.js.  Your script list shows jquery.js as the *last* script, which will reload jquery and thus remove any plugins that were loaded.  Make sure jquery is loaded once and *first* (and pick a version already).

Comment: The SO [tag:toastr] [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/toastr/info) has a starter snippet you can copy.

Answer (score 0):

Could be you are trying to run toastr before it is fully defined.  It works fine here:

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script> toastr.success("s");</script>
```

Comment: This works in my Index.cshtml. However, if I do the same thing in my _Layout.cshtml. I get the error:               Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
    at Sa (VM250 jquery.min.js:3)
    at Function.css (VM250 jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: No doubt your _layout has @sections - make sure your code is in the correct section, in the correct order, without overwriting.